# Adding a Date Variable to our CRM template

Tags: datetime, templates, variables, crm, dayofweek

I am not proficient in coding so please excuse my ignorance.  Below is a CRM email template that we are using.  Would it be possible to edit this code to make the "Wednesday or Thursday" part of the email update based on the actual date so that it outputs the next consecutive days of the week.  For instance if today were Monday it would read "Is there a time Tuesday or Wednesday" that we"...

Thanks so much, greatly appreciated.

```html
<p>Dear Mr X.</p>

<p>The content of our email would be here describing our&nbsp;product to potential clients.</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Is there a time Wednesday or Thursday that we could&nbsp;have a brief 15-minute phone conversation?</p>

<p>[Signature]</p>
```